# show part of an image in animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to show part of an image in animation.I put a `UIImageView` in the `UIScrollView`,and set the UIImageView's frame to `(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight)`,and set UIScrollView's frame's width to `0`. Here is my code

```
self.tiaoView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(316, 74);//tiaoView is an outlet of UIScrollView
[UIView animateWithDuration:5 animations:^{
    CGRect rect=self.tiaoView.frame;
    rect.size.width=316;
    self.tiaoView.frame=rect;}];
```

But when I run it, the whole image is showed immediately, no animation.

Comment: I am not getting you please explain it clearly

Comment: width is already 316. So it should not animate as expected.

Comment: @NeverHopeless-The same thing i was thinking

Comment: @AshutoshMishra I set UIScrollView's frame's width to 0 in storyboard.

Comment: @NeverHopeless  I set UIScrollView's frame's width to 0 in storyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show only part of an image (top, bottom, left or right) by setting `UIImageView`s `contentMode` to any of these

```
UIViewContentModeTop
UIViewContentModeBottom
UIViewContentModeLeft
UIViewContentModeRight
```

setting `clipsToBounds = YES` and changing its frame accordingly. Because `frame` is animatable property, this combination will allow you to animate showing only part of the image.

For example: If you want to show only 20 points from bottom, set `imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeBottom;` and set its `frame`s height to `20`. Image will keep at the bottom edge of `UIImageView` no matter what frame you set to it.

See example code:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 40);
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeLeft;
imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
[self.view addSubview:imageView];

CGRect finalFrame = imageView.frame;
finalFrame.size.width = 40;

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    imageView.frame = finalFrame;
}];
```

This code animates image by expanding its size from 0 size 40.

Comment: Thank you,but this doesn't work.here is my code `//wenZiView is an outlet of UIImageView
    self.wenZiView.contentMode=UIViewContentModeLeft;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{
        CGRect rect= self.wenZiView.frame;
        rect.size.width=316;
        self.wenZiView.frame=rect;
    }];`

Comment: I forgot you need to set `clipsToBounds = YES`. Please see my edited answer with tested example code